# Superset Installation is taking a long time and i see the same log

Tags: apache-superset

I am trying to install superset on a docker image and it seems to be running for 3 hours now and i started to notuce the same logs over and over. I am not sure if this is regular process or should i just stop and restart it over again

Some of the common logs is

> Flask_appbuilder : DB Creation and initialization failed  background
> on this error at https:\sqlachme.me\e\14\e3q8